# Создание триггера для вычисления итоговой цены

Tags: sql-server

Есть три таблицы: VisitLog, Services, PaymentOrder.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно создать триггер при добавлении новой записи в таблицу PaymentOrder, который рассчитывает итоговую цену в зависимости от VisitNumber, по которому можно узнать стоимость услуги. Формула TotalCost = Discount * Cost, если ServiceID в таблице VisitLog равен 4, то TotalCost = Cost

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_PaymentOrder_i ON PaymentOrders
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE PaymentOrders
    SET TotalCost = Services.Cost * PaymentOrders.Discount
    FROM inserted
    INNER JOIN VisitLog ON VisitLog.VisitNumber = inserted.VisitNumber
    INNER JOIN Services ON Services.ServiceID = VisitLog.ServiceID
    INNER JOIN PaymentOrders ON PaymentOrders.PaymentNumber = inserted.PaymentNumber
END
```